# Google Maps Static API - Referer Policy Issue

Tags: google-maps, http-referer, google-maps-static-api

I have created an API Key, assigned Static Map api only and applied referer policy e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

My expectations was this api key should only succeed if http referer header equals to "www.example.com".

When I tried, it's working as below:

1. **Successful** response when referer header is "www.example.com"
2. **Unsuccessful** response when referer header is not blank and some other value
3. **Successful** response when **NO referrer header is provided**.

Point 1 and 2 is fine however I point 3 shouldn't have been successful. Am I missing something? Is this how referer policy implemented for maps?
I tried by creating new keys as well but same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently this is a [known issue](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/google-maps-api-not-the-key-bugs-that-i-found-over-the-years-781840fc82aa) that was reported to Google about 2 years ago and they don't seem to care much. You should contact Google Maps support team if you are concerned about it.

Comment: There's an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124860491) to correct this in Google Maps' Public Issue Tracker